# How do i extend Oracle VM Template Oracle database 19c dev/sdb1 storage space

Tags: linux, oracle, virtual-machine, oracle19c, oraclelinux

I would like to extend the storage of my oracle vm template  for the partition that holds  /u01/ directory which houses all components for database apex and ords.

I would like to know what is the safest way to go about doing this. i read online that using fdisk command I would need to delete the partition. but I a fearful of this and need some guidance

Answer (score 1):

If the disk wasn't set up as an logical volume to begin with then your options are limited. Here's how I would do it (it isn't elegant, but it works):

1. Add a new disk to the system and format/mount it as /u01new
2. Stop all Oracle services
3. Use "cp -pR /u01/* /u01new" to copy everything from the old disk to the new one
4. Unmount /u01
5. Unmount /u01new and remount it as /u01
6. Restart all Oracle services
7. Once you're sure everything is working ok, drop the original disk

Comment: sounds like a good plan... ok but if i want it to be set up as LVM because rn its not isthere a way around that

Comment: I have not tested this myself, but this might work: https://pascalroeleven.nl/2019/03/14/convert-an-existing-linux-file-system-to-lvm/